# How do I edit the views from Roo/gvNIX?

Tags: jsp, spring-roo, gvnix

**How do I edit the views produced from Roo / gvNIX?**

I've got these cool form and table views that they produced thanks to following the tutorials, but I want to fine tune them.

I've tried using the Vaadin plugin in eclipse, but it doesn't seem to recognize jspx.

I've also tried editing with Web Page Editor but eclipse gives me an error.  e.g from the tutorial, src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/sets/*.jspx I just get this:  [Failed to create the part's controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGFrB.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGFrB.png)

I have been able to get the Web Page Editor to work in another Roo project, however, I just need some help in figuring out how to get it do what I want.  For example, I have a nice form generated by Roo for a basic  address entity, where *create.jspx* allows inputs for: street number, street name, city, state and post code.  Having each of these as form-wide fields looks pretty silly.  For example, how do I configure the view so that I have the separate fields for city, state, postcode on one line?  Is this something I should do as a section in the *standard.css* or another css file?

(Using Roo 2.0.0.M1 & gvNIX 2.0.0.M1, Java 1.8, Postgress 9.4, Eclipse Mars.1 - but I think my question is very basic.)

Comment: Nothing?  OK, it might be a beginner question, but throw me a bone.  Just give me the name of a UI tool that you've used for Roo, or a link to a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

JSPX pages generated by Roo or gvNIX haven't been designed with a WYSIWYG tool. They were handcrafted first in a proof project, and then the Web MVC related addons generate the pages using the proof project as a model.

I haven't used visual tool with JSP pages, but in my own experience it pays off learning to edit them by hand. You will need to learn how to use JSP tags and the EL language, but there are a lot of tutorials, like the one available into the [Java EE tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html).

In the case of gvNIX, I advise you to use the bootstrap addon. This will allow you to adjust your forms using the Bootstrap grid system, besides having responsive pages.

Finally, take into account the M1 releases are early ones, and might change a lot before getting to the final one. It's OK if you are just learning, otherwise it would be better to use one of the final available versions ([1.5.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gvnix/files/gvNIX-1.5.0.RELEASE.zip/download) just now).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll have a look at the tutorial you linked.  ATM I can't even figure out how to manually create the single line for City, State, Zip in the JSPX.  Any recommended tutorials on doing that?   Is it possible/advisable to use another tool (with WYSISWYG) to create views using those same controllers.  Any candidate tools?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to advise you about any WYSIWYG tool, since I haven't used any such a tool. Maybe you will need also an HTML and bootstrap tutorial.